# How to validate the first character of text to be a specific number in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create a `textinput` that only accepts numeric characters and the first character must be 3 in React Native.

```
            const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({
                num: '',
            });           

            let numOnly = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
            let valid = true;
    
            if (!inputs.num.trim() || inputs.num.length < 10 || !inputs.num.match(numOnly)) {//if number field is not in correct format
                handleError('Please input phone number correctly', 'phone');
                valid = false;
            }
```

Comment: For what you asked, use this regex `^3\d*\Z`, for what you have in your existing code, `^3\d{9}\Z` should match better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex : `/^3\d{9}$/`

Description:

1. `^` assert position at start of the line
2. `3` first character must be 3.
3. `\d{9}` 9 characters after the first one has to be digits
4. `$` assert position at the end of a line

As you specified the first character, the 9 next ones and start/end of the line, the total length has to be 10.

You can replace `$` by `\Z` for *end of the string* instead of *end of the line*

Answer (score -2):

You can use below Regx to validate phone number:-

```
const reg = /^[0]?[3]\d{9}$/;
if (reg.test(phone) === true) {
  if (phone.length > 9) {
    console.log("valid phone number");
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid phone number");
  }
}
```

You can put the numbers in this array [3] like [3789] that you want to the phone number starts with.

Comment: This is absolutely not what OP asked for, you regex don't start with `3`